# Can I read file content hosted on NodeMCU?

Tags: lua, nodemcu, esplorer

I have uploaded some files to NodeMCU via ESPlorer, and I am able to list them all. The problem is that I don't know what the content of some files is, as they are modified with Lua scripts.

Is it possible to read file content using ESPlorer, or if not is there any other way to check file content hosted on NodeMCU?

Comment: I don't have my NodeMCU handy at the moment so I can't verify this. If `io` module is available (I don't remember) then you can do standard Lua: `print(io.open'xxx':read'a')` to read file xxx. If the `file` module is available then something similar would be `print(file.open 'xxx':read(9999))` using a number bigger than the actual file size.

Comment: @tonypdmtr NodeMCU does not provide the io module. It has been replaced by NodeMCU's file module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in 'View' > 'Show FileManager panel at right'. Then hit the 'Reload' button there and pick from the context menu of the file in question.

[image]